# Can't login in to mysql database with .bat in windows 8.1

Tags: mysql, windows, batch-file, cmd

I'm running windows 8.1.

I created a mysql database in command prompt, through `root user` and granted "grant all on database.* to "user@localhost" identified by "password"". 
Now when i create .bat with one liner:

```
c:\xampp\mysql\bin\mysql -u user@localhost -ppassword
```

It doesn't work, but it worked for windows 7. why?

Comment: Probably you are missing space between p and password `c:\xampp\mysql\bin\mysql -u user@localhost -p password`

Comment: Maybe c:\xampp\mysql\bin\mysql is not a valid folder spec on that machine. Put the line "@echo on" just before your line shown in your question to see that or other problems. Or tell us what result you get.

Comment: What the _It doesn't work_ stands for? Please [edit] your question and add error messages (following @RGuggisberg advice as well) .